# R Likert Package: Increase the facet strip label text size

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

I am using the likert package and followed [this example](https://github.com/jbryer/likert/blob/master/demo/likert.R). I wanted to use the grouping figure like they did. The group figure looks like this:

[image: Group]

I need to increase the font size of the facet strip labels (for example, "I read only if I have to"). How can I do that in R?

Also, how can we change the facet strip orders? For example, I want the orders be like (2,1,5,3,4, ...).

Comment: You can use the standard ggplot theme elements. In this case add `+  theme(strip.text=element_text(size=15))` and choose the `size` you desire.

Comment: Thanks. That worked :). Any suggestions on how the group orders can be changed?

Comment: Don't ask a new question in comments, start a new question.

Comment: Set the ordering by converting the grouping variable to a factor. Use the `levels` argument to set the order. See `?factor`. There are also numerous SO questions about group ordering in ggplot2. Also see [this tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7433_4537ea5073dc4162950abb715f513469.html).